# Using dojo for grails ajax requests

Tags: javascript, ajax, grails, dojo

I am using `Grails 1.3.9` and I want to use `Dojo` for my `ajax` requests. I have included `dojo` in my head tag like this: `<g:javascript library="dojo"/>`. My network traffic is showing that this script is loaded fine. But when I check my generated source code I see that `Grails` generated the `Ajax` request for prototype(probably default). How can I force `Grails` to use `Dojo` to generate `ajax` requests?

Comment: Did you install the dojo plugin (see http://grails.org/plugin/dojo) ? If so, which version did you install ?

Answer (score 2):

This may be out of context since you are using an older version of Grails, but have a look at [javascripts in newer versions of Grails](http://grails.org/doc/2.2.1/ref/Tags/javascript.html). Particularly,

> library (optional) - The name of the library to include. Typical
>   values include "jquery", "prototype", "scriptaculous", "yahoo" or
>   "dojo" but plugins can contribute new providers. If the Resources
>   plugin is installed, no link to the library will be rendered
>   immediately. Rather, it will include the resource module with the same
>   name as the library and let Resources do the rest. This means you must
>   have a resource module declared with the same name, as if you had used
>   an `<r:use module="jquery"/>` tag.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is built-in support for Dojo (as of Grails 2.3.9), so you need to do a full, manual Dojo initialization in your page (as described in the Dojo docs).

There is a slightly out-of-date Dojo Plugin for Dojo v1.7, that helps a lot with Grails integration issues.